# I cannot print floats

Tags: python, math

I am trying to write my own code for square roots and the program can only print roots with perfect squares and no decimals which is not very helpful.
I would like the program to be able to print all roots.

This is what I have so far

```
while True:

    def frange(start, stop, step=1):
        i = start
        while i < stop:
            yield i
            i += step
    userInput=input("Enter a natural number:>>>")
    userInput=int(userInput)
    for i in frange(1,(userInput+1)/2):
        if i*i==userInput:

            print(i)
```

Comment: Move the def frange block out of the while loop and change your int(userInput) to float(userInput) and you're good to go!

Comment: Reading your question better, you'll need to change your frange() function to output floats.  The i value you print is an output of your frange() function, which is always going to be an integer.  Even if you cast it to float, it will still be only whole numbers.

Comment: Your algorithm is a brute-force search for integer square roots, so *of course* it will only print integer square roots of perfect squares. For arbitrary square roots -- you would need a radically different approach, one involving e.g. Newton's method. Or -- just use `math.sqrt()` if you don't want to reinvent the wheel. By the way, I doubt that you have any trouble *printing* floats, hence your title is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
userInput=input("Enter a natural number:>>>")
userInput=int(userInput)
```

Do this:

```
userInput = float(input("Enter a number:>>>"))
```

`int` allows only whole numbers, `float` allows decimals.

EDIT: I too needed to re-read your question

Thinking about it, much of your code is unnecessary. You can simply do:

```
userInput = float(input("Enter a number:>>>"))
root = userInput ** 0.5
print(str(root))
```